# How to use "at" unix command to schedule a python script directly from terminal?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to use `at` command in the following,

`at 19:32 04/02/2015 < /usr/bin/python /home/myscript.py`

But I get the error

```
syntax error. Last token seen: /
Garbled time
```

I'd like to run the script directly from shell without having to placing the python command in a `.sh` script and using `at -f python.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Two problems;

- The `at` date format is funny (not quite [Yoda](https://twitter.com/html5_yoda/status/545129883438166016) funny but still).
- You are trying to use file redirection on something which isn't a file.

Try this instead;

```
at 19:32 Apr 2 <<':'
  /usr/bin/python /home/myscript.py
:
```

If I am reading the `at` timespec correctly, the year field is only two digits. It's still dd/mm/yy not American wacky mm/dd/yy.

```
at 19:32 02/04/15 <<<'/usr/bin/python /home/myscript.py'
```

Here strings are Bash only; yet another alternative is

```
echo '/usr/bin/python /home/myscript.py' | at 19:32 02/04/15
```

Comment: Everything right, except the timespec works on the "American wacky mm/dd/yy" :)

Comment: Hmm, looks like that is locale-dependent, actually. I was looking at an ancient BSD man page.

Comment: Ah, echoing any script/command does'nt seem to work here, does it work on your end?  `echo "any_command" | at 19:32 02/04/15`

Comment: Huh?  `at` doesn't care (and indeed cannot know) how the shell connects its standard input before it runs.  A pipe is just as fine as a here document or (in Bash) a here string.